# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing in hibernate master table involved

Tags: hibernate

I have a master table named bmu_mstr and corresponding entity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bmu_mstr")
@JsonIgnoreType
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@bmuId")
public class BmuMaster implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8284996311089344328L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bmu_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer bmuId;

    @Column(name = "bmu_desc")
    private String bmuDesc;

    public BmuMaster() {
    }

    public BmuMaster(Integer bmuId) {
        this.bmuId = bmuId;
```

and other table is comp_rsc_move_employee which has tranfer_from and transfer_to column..basically the bmu_id of the bmu master table. thecorresponding class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comp_rsc_move_employee")
public class CompRscEmployee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer rscId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transfer_from")
    private BmuMaster transferFrom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transfer_to")
    private BmuMaster transferTo;
```

now I want to update data in comp_rsc_move_employee table

```
        CompRscEmployee compRscEmployee = new CompRscEmployee();


        compRscEmployee.setTransferFrom(new BmuMaster(employeeDetails.getTransferFrom()));
        compRscEmployee.setTransferTo(new BmuMaster(employeeDetails.getTransferTo()));

        CompRscEmployee rscEmp = compDao.saveOrUpdate(compRscEmployee)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CommonException("Unable to save or update CompRscEmployee data"));
```

But now when ever i want to save CompRscEmployee hibernate tells **'object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing'**

I searched all stackoverflow thread but did not come up with my scenario..My BmuMaster is MASTER table i dont want to save data in that table when inserting in CompRscEmployee table. obviously i can change the entity class CompRscEmployee and can change the data type from BmuMaster to Integer. But I dont want to do that.. Any ideas how to achieve that?? It seems like a very basic problem. But i am unable to do that as i am quite new to hibernate..

Answer (score 0):

You should load the `BmuMaster` instances from the database, not create new ones, to pass into the `setTransferFrom` and `setTransferTo` methods.

Not sure how your code is setup, but something like this

```
BmuMaster from = masterDao.findById(employeeDetails.getTransferFrom())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CommonException("Unable to find department" + employeeDetails.getTransferFrom()));
BmuMaster to = masterDao.findById(employeeDetails.getTransferTo())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CommonException("Unable to find department" + employeeDetails.getTransferTo()));

CompRscEmployee compRscEmployee = new CompRscEmployee();
compRscEmployee.setTransferFrom(from);
compRscEmployee.setTransferTo(to);

CompRscEmployee rscEmp = compDao.saveOrUpdate(compRscEmployee)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CommonException("Unable to save or update CompRscEmployee data"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..But transferFrom and  transferTo are coming from user input. So i dont want extra database round trip to fetch the details . I just want to directly save the data in child table.

Comment: Well, that's the tool you're working with. You're asking an ORM to map objects to the database. But you're now saying you want to work directly with the database relational mapping yourself. You're ignoring some aspects of this too, such as invalid references in the `from` and `to` values supplied by the user. Don't try to work around the tool you've selected. Either use it as it's designed, or use another tool. If you don't want the query for each department each time, perhaps you can cache the results of a larger query, re-attach the entity from the cache and then save the relationship

Comment: I guess i may not make myself clear. Ok. Suppose there is a Country table with id and name and corresponding class has also the same. Now I want to save the country id i another say employee table. So I have two option. In employee class I can either make country as String or country as object. when it is string then there is no problem But if i want to save country as a object then the error that i mentioned above occur. Now my question is why I need to save data in Country tbl as it is master tbl and  as you suggest to find it by id , why would I do that because it already submitted by user